# Replace python list comprehension generating 3D array with numpy functions

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I have two matrices (numpy arrays), **mu** and **nu**. From these I would like to create a third array as follows:

**new_array**_{j, k, l} = **mu**_{l, k} **nu**_{j, k}

I can do it naively using list comprehensions:

```
[[[mu[l, k] * nu[j, k] for k in np.arange(N)] for l in np.arange(N)] for j in np.arange(N)]
```

but it quickly becomes slow.

How can I create **new_array** using numpy functions which should be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                               

import numpy as np

# example data
mu = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
nu = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5) + 20

# get array sizes
nl, nk = mu.shape
nj, nk_ = nu.shape
assert(nk == nk_)

# get arrays with dimensions (nj, nk, nl)

# in the case of mu3d, we need to add a slowest varying dimension
# so (after transposing) this can be done by cycling through the data
# nj times along the slowest existing axis and then reshaping
mu3d = np.concatenate((mu.transpose(),) * nj).reshape(nj, nk, nl)

# in the case of nu3d, we need to add a new fastest varying dimension 
# so this can be done by repeating each element nl times, and again it
# needs reshaping
nu3d = nu.repeat(nl).reshape(nj, nk, nl)

# now just multiple element by element
new_array = mu3d * nu3d

print(new_array)
```

Gives:

```
>>> mu
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

>>> nu
array([[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])

>>> nj, nk, nl
(3, 5, 2)

>>> mu3d
array([[[0, 5],
        [1, 6],
        [2, 7],
        [3, 8],
        [4, 9]],

       [[0, 5],
        [1, 6],
        [2, 7],
        [3, 8],
        [4, 9]],

       [[0, 5],
        [1, 6],
        [2, 7],
        [3, 8],
        [4, 9]]])

>>> nu3d
array([[[20, 20],
        [21, 21],
        [22, 22],
        [23, 23],
        [24, 24]],

       [[25, 25],
        [26, 26],
        [27, 27],
        [28, 28],
        [29, 29]],

       [[30, 30],
        [31, 31],
        [32, 32],
        [33, 33],
        [34, 34]]])

>>> new_array
array([[[  0, 100],
        [ 21, 126],
        [ 44, 154],
        [ 69, 184],
        [ 96, 216]],

       [[  0, 125],
        [ 26, 156],
        [ 54, 189],
        [ 84, 224],
        [116, 261]],

       [[  0, 150],
        [ 31, 186],
        [ 64, 224],
        [ 99, 264],
        [136, 306]]])
```

Comment: you can take advantage of broadcasting rules when creating the 3d arrays.  Don't need repeats.

Comment: @hpaulj I was reluctant to use broadcasting because of fear that it would use some heuristic to decide which axes to broadcast along, that could give the wrong answer in the event that there were dimensions of the same size. I don't know if those fears were unfounded.

Comment: @hpaulj If you can propose a separate answer based on broadcasting, that would be great. But there would be five cases to test: all dimensions (nj,nk,nl) different, the three different cases where two dimensions are equal, and all dimensions the same.

Comment: You still need the transpose.  Broadcasting rules are unambiguous.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that is obviously hard to avoid. Again, if you know how safely to use broadcasting, I'm sure that could be faster and use less memory than my solution. I just wasn't confident about it.

Comment: Thanks @alaniwi this is a helpful solution. I am wondering if you can comment about your thought process with approaching the problem? In 2D I can just about visualise things fine but struggle in higher dimensions - typically I use lots of trial and error until I get the indices labelled correctly

Comment: @Mashy Not sure I have much to add to the comments. We know that mu has axes (L,K) and nu has axes (J,K) and we want a result with axes (J,K,L), so nu is going to want transposing, and then after that (if not using implicit broadcasting) we are going to have to add these extra axes. Fortunately because it is in one case adding a slowest varying axis this just means repeating the whole array the right number of times, and the other case it is adding a fastest varying axis this is repeating each element the right number of times. Adding an axis in the middle could be trickier...

Comment: @Mashy Trial and error is okay, but it is really helpful to make sure that all the dimensions are different while you're experimenting.

Comment: @Mashy Sorry, typo above, too late to correct, *mu* will want transposing.

Comment: @alaniwi yes thanks, I noticed it earlier - your explanation there was quite helpful

Answer (score 3):

Two quick solutions (without my usual proofs and explanations):

```
res = np.einsum('lk,jk->jkl', mu, nu) 

res = mu.T[None,:,:] * nu[:,:,None]     # axes in same order as result
```

Comment: I like it, and see what you mean about broadcasting now. I hadn't realised you were explicitly adding a size-1 dimension to both arrays prior to multiplying, just thought that you were talking about multiplying perhaps a 3d by 2d array and relying on it working out which dimension to broadcast. It all makes good sense now.

Comment: @hpaulj Those are both very helpful methods. I wasn't aware of numpy.einsum until now, but I think I will start to use it all the time. My original physics problem has some more terms which I wrote explicitly in terms of numpy.matmul, but some others for which einsum seems like a much neater solution. Cheers.

Comment: @Mashy `einsum` looks very useful. (I hadn't encountered it either.) Although it's not clear from the above how one would represent an operation other than multiplication.